# linux container running on windows host -- access to host docker

Tags: windows, docker

I have an ubuntu container running on docker for windows. How can I give it access to the docker daemon that is running on my windows host?

Note: I am not trying to run docker-in-docker, i.e., inside my container, `docker ps` should show containers running on the host machine's docker daemon. If my host machine was running linux, this would be achieved by mounting `/var/run/docker.sock` inside the container -- is there a similar technique when the host machine runs windows?

This is my docker destkop version: `Docker Desktop 4.12.0 (85629) is currently the newest version available.`

Answer (score 0):

You can expose the daemon via TCP socket, it's a setting under General